# Put checkbox before and after text end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

[image]

Is this possible? As long as text fit on screen text alignment will be after the first button. Also if text is multiline and finishes in middle, checkbox will be after text which will show white space in between.

Comment: try to use ImageSpan and make it Clickable to change state of image

Answer (score 2):

just copy and paste the following code. hopefully it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="CheckBox any text  that is multilined you want bla bla bla."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @Tanzeela Nisar. Welcome to Stackoverflow! :) A good answer will explain the *why* as well :)